# AJAX call not working dynamically?

Tags: php, ajax

I have the following Script:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#additem').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'php/additem.php',
                 data: {itemName: $('#itemName').val()},
                 data: {pricetotal: $('#price').val()},
                 data: {description: $('#description').val()},
                 success: function(data)
                 {
                    Can i call a separate ajax query here? I want to repull my two tables data so the resulting itemadd seems dynamic.
                 }
             });
         });
     });
```

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="content-boxes style-two top-column clearfix animated flipInY" style="opacity: 1;">
                        <div class="content-boxes-text">
                            <form action="php/additem.php" method="post" class="form-inline pull-right">
                                <h4>'.$row['itemName'].'</h4><input id="itemName" type="hidden" name="itemName" value="'.$row['itemName'].'">
                                <h3>$'.$price.'</h3><input id="price" type="hidden" name="pricetotal" value="'.$price.'">   
                                <img src="../wholesale/img/sourdough.jpg" class="img-reponsive">
                                <p>'.$row['description'].'</p><input id="description" type="hidden" name="description" value="'.$row['description'].'">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Qty</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="number" name="qty" class="form-control" id="qtyitem" placeholder="How Many?">
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" id="additem" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <!-- //.content-boxes-text -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- //.content-boxes -->
                </div>
```

The problem is when i submit the form the page reloads like a normal query.
The page should not refresh and the item adding should happen dynamically.

I am having trouble with the idea: 
My initial loading pulls up data from two tables, so would it be best to recall that initial ajax query after i have added an item?

Please give me reasoning to anything you write so i can learn from this.
Thank you all.

```
    session_start();
include('db_config.php');

$date = date("Y-m-d");
$itemname = $_POST['itemName'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
$price = $_POST['pricetotal'] * $qty;
$id = $_SESSION['customer_id'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (deliveryDate, customerId, itemName, qty, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($date, $id, $itemname, $qty, $price));

header('Location: ../order.php');
```

JS SCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.form-inline').on("submit",function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'php/additem.php',
             data: {
                  itemName: $('#itemName').val(), 
                  pricetotal: $('#price').val(), 
                  description: $('#description').val(),
                  qty: $('#qtyitem').val()
             },
             success: function(data)
             {
                alert(data);
             }
         });
      });
 });   
 </script>
```

Comment: alert($('#qtyitem').val()) after event.preventDefault();  
see what you get in alert box

Comment: alert comes up blank :/ this is really confusing, have i named it correctly?

Comment: use the value from input name instead like this **$("input[name='field-name']").val()**

Comment: PHP file cannot find the index qty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

additem button is a submit button so it performs default operation

to avoid your page reload do this

use :    event.preventDefault();

change your code to

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.form-inline').on("submit",function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'php/additem.php',
             data: {
                      itemName: $('#itemName').val(), 
                      pricetotal: $('#price').val(), 
                      description: $('#description').val()
             },
             success: function(data)
             {
                // perform action
             }
         });
     });
 });
```

Comment: Do i need to add anything to php file so the result can come back?

Comment: yes echo your result from php page as a string, so you will get it here as it is in data and use data from success to perform furthur action,

Comment: made changes to your ajax, data should be used like this

Comment: Ill add my php perhaps something must need to be changed here since nothing is updating.

Comment: remove the header : header('Location: ../order.php'); and echo something,
use alert(data); in your ajax success function to see what returns from your php page  **is your ajax working now**

Comment: Okay it seems to work but one minor issue left: when i add:
qty: $('#exampleInputAmount').val() to the script, and then echo $qty from the php, i get no value? When the value should be what i entered.

Comment: see if the exampleinputamount isnt used somewhere else before, id may be causing a conflict,

Comment: I changed the id, i dont think its a conflict since it still shows as nothing.
To confirm when i submit without ajax then it works.

Comment: did you put a comma before **qty: $('#exampleInputAmount').val()**

Comment: When i add this to the page it does not run? I have a similar ajax call using the same document ready? how can i combine them into a JS file?

Comment: create a ajax_call.js file put your ajax codes in document ready and include the file using script tag

Comment: I have confirmed that there is a comma, i will update the scripts on the question for your review now

Comment: Additionally after adding this script into the js file, the script does not execute, meaning the php requests processes like a normal request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Change button type "submit" to "button"

```
 <button type="submit" id="additem" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>

to

 <button type="button" id="additem" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>

 or

<input type="button"  id="additem" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add"/>
```